# getting error when opening an external Google Scripts sheet from within a Main Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Project with the following sheets within it:

```
KDCLog
KDCAlerts
KDCAssets
```

Using Google Scripts I open the "active" Log (which is expected to be **"KDCLog"**).

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (activeSheet.getName() !== "KDCLog" ) return;
```

After this is done, I am attempting to open another (external) sheet. To do this, I followed the instructions below:

```
ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70070131/form-data-submit-to-external-sheet-google-script
      //open external sheet
      var extSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Insert External Spreadsheet ID here");
      var extSH = extSS.getSheetByName("Sheet1 External");
```

I followed the Message here to **identify the *gid*** (it is the one with 8 up-arrow-votes)
reference: [Get Google Sheet by ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26682269/get-google-sheet-by-id)

So what I finally wound up with is:

```
var extSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(1591999114);
var extSH = extSS.getSheetByName("KDCAlerts");
```

**But when executing the 2 statements above, I get the following message:**

```
Error   Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
    at onEdit(Code:150:32)
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help, hints or advice would be greatly appreciated!

TIA

@Cooper - Thanks for the response!

---

### UPDATE 1:

I made the following change:

```
//https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b5qiNH8c4wg0h1owr-P3OLRuLf-8dTBgRU9cHLBbd2A/edit#gid=1591999114

var extSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1b5qiNH8c4xxxxxxxx-P3OLRuLf-8dTBgRU9cHLBbd2A');
var extSH = extSS.getSheetByName("KDCAlerts");
```

-- AND --

I found a message that referenced this link here:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes

I made the change to the **appscript.json** file as follows:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/Chicago",
  "dependencies": {},
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "webapp": {
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING",
    "access": "ANYONE_ANONYMOUS"
  },
  "oauthScopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
  ]

}
```

Still getting the error.

---

### UPDATE 2:

Thanks for the response again. I made the changes below.

```
function creatTrigger() {
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "onMyEdit").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("onMyEdit").forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive()).onEdit().create();
  }
}

function onMyEdit(e) {

  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "KDCLog" ) {
    var extSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1b5qiNHxxxxxxxxowr-P3OLRuLf-8dTBgRU9cHLBbd2A');
    var extSH = extSS.getSheetByName("KDCAlerts");
  }
  else { return; }

.....
.....
.....
}
```

The message I am getting now is:

```
Script function not found: onEdit
```

What did I do wrong?

TIA

Comment: In `openById()` the id is a string. It looks like the id that you are using an index for a sheet not a spreadsheet.  Also opening another spreadsheet requires permissions so that will force you into using and installable onEdit trigger rather than a simple trigger.

Comment: @Cooper - thanks for the response! I made some changes and updated the message.

Comment: Please check your triggers in the editor and see if you have another installable trigger for onEdit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function creatTrigger() {
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "onMyEdit").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("onMyEdit").forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive()).onEdit().create();
  }
}

function onMyEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "KDCLog" ) {
    var extSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xssid");
      var extSH = extSS.getSheetByName("Sheet1 External");
  }
      
}
```

Comment: I made the changes. The error I am getting now is fussing about "onEdit" not existing.

Comment: If you create an installable trigger then it should not be name onEdit.  In my example it was name onMyEdit().  You can name it whatever you wish except onEdit.

Comment: Do I need to change the main Spreadsheet so that it refers to "onMyEdit" when changing a cell on the Spreadsheet and not "onEdit".  When working on the Spreadsheet, when making changes, it looks for the onEdit function

Comment: The simple trigger is generated on any user edit of the spreadsheet and by default the onEdit function is executed if it exists.  The onMyEdit() function will only receive the installable trigger that was created for it.   The only thing you need to do with it is create the trigger by executing the createTrigger function which is setup so that you can only create one of them because multiple triggers can cause difficult to troubleshoot problems.

Comment: all of the triggers that you see in the triggers section of the editor are installable triggers and I was guessing that there must have been one that was attached to an onEdit function which is something you really don't want to do.

Comment: " I was guessing that there must have been one that was attached to an onEdit function" - you were right.  There was a trigger connected to an "onEdit" function. I have deleted all of the triggers and am going to try to create  a new one

Comment: Hi again - thanks for all of the help! It seems that the errors have gone away. I am looking at this group of videos to get an understanding on some topics: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=google+sheets+triggers+onEdit   Thanks again!

Comment: You can use that create trigger function to create the onMyEdit trigger.